# Spark Scala SBT Task Failed

Tags: scala, sbt

When I tray using spark with Scala in SBT build system to read a Json file a have the error:
[image]

and my SBT file is:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.1"


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector" % "10.0.5"
```

I tray to change all "3.3.1" and "10.0.5" to "3.0.1" and it still the same problem

Comment: In IntelliJ, click on "untitled" in the error list to get more details. Or use SBT directly from cli.

Comment: Spark `3.3.1` has Scala 2.13 compatible binaries on Maven Central,  its just the mongo-connector which is causing the issue. So, you will need to change to Scala `2.12.x`. Also, the mongo connector line has `%` which needs to be changed to `%%` similar to the other two lines.

Comment: Also, `mongo-spark-connector 10.0.5` targets `Spark 3.1.2`, so while it might be possible that it will also work with `Spark 3.3.1`, it is safer to use `Spark 3.1.2` instead of `Spark 3.3.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a 2.12 version of Scala, since those dependencies do not all have 2.13 built.

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.11"
```

Look at the screenshot from Maven to see that 2.13 isn't listed for those versions (or at all).

[image]

Comment: Spark `3.3.1` has Scala 2.13 compatible binaries on Maven Central,  its just the mongo-connector which is causing the issue. So, you will need to change to Scala `2.12.x`. Also, the mongo connector line has `%` which needs to be changed to `%%` similar to the other two lines.

Comment: Correct - I believe even if any dependency isn't compatible, then there is an error about that. I believe that the mongo connector doesn't need `%%` for that specific version, because 10.0.5 doesn't have any scala versions specified. The above is what worked on my env.

Comment: Yes, that probably means that mongo-connector is Java based now. So... no need to add that `%%`.